# PHP -displaying 12 items of an associative array with specific key and value

Tags: php

```
<?php
foreach($catalog as $id=> $item) {
    echo get_item_html($id,$item);
}
// here is the functions page code :
function get_item_html($id,$item){
    $output = "<li><a href='#'><img src='" 
    . $item["img"] . "' alt='" 
    . $item["title"] . "' />" 
    . "<p>View Details</p>"
    . "</a></li>";
    return $output;
}
?>
```

I have used it for displaying product categories i checked several time but I did find any error but it display undefined variable 
please help me to find out this solution

Comment: Which is your undefined variable ?

Comment: the answer would be $id => $item  just need one space